# php jquery json multiple value

Tags: php, json

i am learning on how to parse json using jquery

PHP

```
foreach($cars as $car)
{       
    $output['carID'][] = $car->carID;
    $output['carName'][] = $car->carName;
}
echo jsonEncode($output);
```

JSON

```
{"carID":["1","2"],"carName":["BMW","Mercedez Benz"]}
```

My javascript

```
$.getJSON('/cars.php', { carID: carID }, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        for(j=0; j < item[item.carName]; j++) {
            console.log(item[item.carName][j]);
        }
    });
});
```

I think my code is entirely wrong because its not working.

how can i get the value inside of `["1","2"]` ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `["1","2"]` is the value of `carId`, and it is an `array`. Haven't you tried `item['carID'][0]`, `item['carID'][1]`?

Comment: how do i get the value of 1,bmw and 2,mercedez benz using javascript?

Comment: It's not the "value of 1" that you're looking for. It's the value at *index 0*, which happens to be "1".

Comment: put it as answer? i manage to solve it, thanks to your guidance Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the "value of 1" that you're looking for. It's the value at *index 0*, which happens to be "1".

`["1","2"]` is the value of `carID`, and it is an `array`.

Try accessing it this way:

```
alert(item.carID[0]); // will alert "1"
alert(item.carID[1]); // will alert "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, array indexes start from "0" in many languages, so you need something like this to get array values in your code;

```
var data = {"carID":["1","2"],"carName":["BMW","Mercedez Benz"]};

$.each(data.carID, function(key, val){
   var i = 0, id;
   while(id = val[i++]) console.log(id);
});

// or just simply use
console.log(data.carID[0]);
```